# Manage inputs from external command in a powershell script

Tags: powershell

First, I would like to apologize in case that the title is not descriptive enough, I'm having a hard time dealing with this problem. I'm trying to build an automation for a svn merge using a powershell script that will be executed for another process. The function that I'm using looks like this:

```
function($target){
   svn merge $target
}
```

Now, my problem occurs when there are conflicts in the merge. The default behavior of the command is request an input from the user and proceed accordingly. I would like to automatize this process using predefined values (show the differences and then postpone the merge), but I haven't found a way to do it. In summary, the workflow that I am looking to accomplish is the following:

1. Detect whether the command execution requires any input to proceed
2. Provide a default inputs (in my particular case "df" and then "p")

Is there any way to do this in powershell? Thank you so much in advance for any help/clue that you can provide me.

Edit:

To clarify my question: I would like to automatically provide a value when a command executed within a powershell script require it, like in the following example:

[Requesting user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rwDs.jpg)

Edit 2:

Here is a test using the snippet provided by @mklement0. Unfortunately, It didn't work as expected, but I thought it was wort to add this edition to clarify the question per complete

**Expected behavior:**
[image: Expected behavior]

**Actual result:**
[image: Actual result]

Comment: @mklement0 Exactly, with this approach the prompts never shown for whatever reason. I am changing my approach to simply notify that there are conflicts to resolve. I can do that using your approach which allows me to bypass the user input. In the mid time I will look for additional documentation in the svn side. But in any case, thanks for your input, it really helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it; while it won't help you with `svn`, I've fixed and undeleted my answer to show how it _could_ work _if_ `svn` prompted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**:

- **This answer does not solve the OP's problem, because the specific target utility, `svn`, apparently *suppresses prompts* when the process' stdin input isn't coming from a *terminal* (console).**
- For utilities that do still prompt, however, the solution below should work, within the constraints stated.
- Generally, before attempting to simulate user input, it's worth investigating whether the target utility offers *programmatic* control over the behavior, via its *command-line options*, which is both simpler and more robust.

---

While it would be far from trivial to *detect* whether a given external command is prompting for user input:

- you can *blindly* send the presumptive responses,
- which assumes that no situational variations are needed (except if a particular calls happens *not* to prompt at all, in which case the input is ignored).

Let's assume the following batch file, `foo.cmd`, which puts up 2 prompts and echoes the input:

```
@echo off
echo begin
set /p "input1=prompt 1: "
echo [%input1%]
set /p "input2=prompt 2: "
echo [%input2%]
echo end
```

Now let's send responses `one` and `two` to that batch file:

```
C: PS> Set-Content tmp.txt -Value 'one', 'two'; ./foo.cmd '<' tmp.txt; Remove-Item tmp.txt
begin
prompt 1: one
[one]
prompt 2: two
[two]
end
```

Note:

- For reasons unknown to me, the **use of an intermediate *file* is necessary for this approach to work on *Windows*** - `'one', 'two' | ./foo.cmd` does *not* work.

  - Note how the `<` must be represented as `'<'` to ensure that it is passed through to `cmd.exe` and not interpreted by PowerShell up front (where `<` isn't supported).
- By contrast, `'one', 'two' | ./foo` *does* work on *Unix* platforms (PowerShell Core).

Comment: Even thought it didn't work for my specific case, I'm making this as the accepted answer because definitely addressed my initial concern. Also, thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the SVN command line output into a variable and parse through that and branch as you desire.  Each line of output is stored into a new enumerator (cli output stored in PS variables is in array format)

```
$var = & svn merge $target
$var
```

Comment: First, thank you so much for your answer. This snippet with help me with another problem that I have to resolve. However, I think I didn't explain correctly my problem. For that reason, I added additional information to the question to clarify what I am looking for.